# PHP Sessions not staying set w/ header redirect in Wordpress

Tags: php, forms, redirect, post, get

I've been trying to get this for script to work for the last couple days, but for whatever reason sessions are becoming unset with header redirects.

If $_POST are set I perform error checking and set the $_POST variables & errors as session variables. This process takes place before the page loads in the page head. After the sessions have been set the header redirect reloads the page to clear the $_POST array.

Once the page loads the sessions are set to variables within a function inside the body of the page. The sessions are then unset and destroyed.

The problem I'm having is that the header redirects are loading the page with an empty session array. I added a var_dump to my page to check what was being passed from the session array. When the page uses the header redirect the array is empty, but if the redirect is removed the sessions contain all the correct variables.

I don't understand why because the sessions are unset using session_unset() and session_destroy() after the page has loaded and the sessions have been set as standard variables.

**SOLVED:**

The problem was with how I started the session in wordpress. Even though it was started before any HTML was parsed I still had to pass it through as an initializing function in functions.php. 1 just sets the priority.

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
```

This function can be used or changed as needed the important thing is that the session starts when WP is initialized. Hopefully this helps others with similar problems and saves a couple days of trial and error.

Comment: has the session been started in **all** files using sessions? It's not shown/mentioned, and nowhere under *"Passing and Destroying Session Data:"*

Comment: 1. Are you calling `session_start()` in the page to which you are redirecting? 2. Are you aware that `session_destroy()` deletes all session data? 3. Were you maybe thinking of [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, all this is actually on the same page. The first block is in the <head> and the second block is within the <body>

Comment: Plus, I don't know why you're using `if()` and a ternary operator below that for the same session arrays. Ternaries are supposed to replace `if/else`.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for the suggestion on the if statement I believe I cleaned that up correctly. Good call on the error checking. I'm getting undefined errors for index dob-day and dob-year from the first block i posted. But I don't know why because if they are not set they should be null.

Comment: You're welcome. Now, I'd take a wild guess and say that those elements are either not named, or there's a typo or spaces. Many ways it can go wrong.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I went ahead and added my form as well. There do not appear to be any typos. The error refers to dob-day line `if (isset($_POST['submit'])&&empty($_POST['dob-day'])|| $_POST['dob-day'] < 1 || $_POST['dob-day'] > 31){` and the same line for year. But I don't know why because everything looks right and I even have it set to null by default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80715/discussion-between-nickyb-and-fred-ii).